# socket.io creates one more connection after reconnecting

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying a simple chat application [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-socketio-and) with socket.io and node.js. Every time I restart the node.js server, socket.io automatically reconnects and somehow creates one more connection to the server, i.e. the client now receives the same chat message twice. How do I fix this?

Comment: your link is expired, share your code here. edit your Question for understanding us. Actually I am here for finding answer, but without knowing this question, how can I apply answer. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default on disconnect socket.io reconnects the lost connection, which re runs the `connect` event. So everytime it reconnects you add one more event listener for recieving messages. So you get multiple number of messages equal to server restarts/connection loss.

```
Incoming Chat: 
Connected
dsdadsada
Disconnected                         //recieved by 1st listener
Connected                            //added 2nd listener
adasd
Disconnected                         //recieved by 1st listener
Disconnected                         //recieved by 2nd listener
Connected                            //added 3rd listener
```

You should listen to the first connect using `once` instead of `on`, which runs eventhandler the first time only. Try

```
iosocket.once('connect', function () {
```

instead of

```
iosocket.on('connect', function () {
```

Comment: Ideally you should not be adding event listeners (or any other application features) on connection.

Comment: On the server-side, this can be fixed using a namespace. This let you use `once` for toe `connect` event of the client on the server, too. Sadly, we don't have `once` for the server directly: `io.once('connect', (socket: SocketIO.Socket) => { })` gave a compilining error in TS, while `io.of('/xyz').once('connect', (socket: SocketIO.Socket) => { })` works well.

Comment: @Shamps could you clarify why it's not a good practice?

Comment: @igortp If you register the event handler using the "on" method when the app initialises, you do not need to do it on every connection. The callback will be fired when the websocket reconnects and new messages are received. If you add event handlers on each connection then you will need to manage the removal also on disconnection which is unnecessary. Handlers left around could cause memory leaks

Comment: The once solution isn't enough because it prevents the reconnection to work because socket.io trigger on connect when reconnecting the client. So a better solution is the one of @klchow916

Answer (score 6):

Try to write the **index.html** in this way instead:

```
 iosocket.on('connect', function () {
      $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li>Connected</li>'));
 });
 
 iosocket.on('message', function(message) {
      $('#incomingChatMessages').append($('<li></li>').text(message));
 });

 iosocket.on('disconnect', function() {
      $('#incomingChatMessages').append('<li>Disconnected</li>');
 });
```

It may be caused by the other 2 eventlisteners was registered to the connect event.
When the client disconnected, the other 2 listeners will still here and doesn't get unregistered.

Official documentation about [Duplicate event registration](https://socket.io/docs/v4/troubleshooting-connection-issues/#duplicate-event-registration)

Comment: I think your solution  is a better one. THE IMPORTANT THING HERE IS THAT IN THE CLIENT SCRIPT,YOU SPERATED THE OTHER EVENTS FROM THE 'CONNECT' EVENTS. (WROTE THEM OUTSIDE THE CONNECT EVENT)

Comment: I prefer this answer because the other one, using once, prevents the reconnection to properly work

Comment: I added the official doc link