# Duplicate message shown by socket io

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis, socket.io, phpredis

I am using redis for notification and it works like this -

When user1 has a notification to share with his friends, I publish that message to all channels of each friend of the user. Using socket.io and node, message is pushed to each friend as subscription part is handled using node.

This works fine until connection is lost. 
At this time, on reconnect, I am finding instead of 1, 2 publishes are happening to friend's channels although only 1 activity happened like last case..

> Is their any config using which duplicate publish can be avoided on
>   reconnect ?

Also finding, on reconnect it is trying to connect using secondary transports as well .. Can this be issue ?

Comment: Does this answer help http://stackoverflow.com/a/16796375/568109 ?

Comment: I tried it, it is not yet solved ..

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Same problem here. Every reconnect adds 1 extra message per `.emit()`

Comment: using jquery "once" solved it ..

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that on each connection

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
//...
});
```

you subscribe to redis

```
redisClient.subscribe('activity:*');
```

There is no need to connect to redis each time. You should connect to redis just before socket connection.