# Socket io connects to multiple sockets on reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, redis, socket.io

I have one application where I have implemented notification using using Node js , socket io and redis.

There I have successfully configured publisher and subscriber in node js. Using socket io I can show the messages on client like as realtime.

My design is 1 publisher publishes to many channels and every user is only listening to his own channel.

I publishes to channel1 and channel2 and as the users are listening to their channels only, they are getting their respective messages only one time.

Till Now it worked fine, smoothly.

> But here my problem starts. When the internet goes offline it tries to reconnect and when it again establishes its connection, on every single publish it starts to subscribe twice and as a result of that messeges are showing twice.

My code is something like this on server subscriber side

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var channelName = "channel"+socket.handshake.query.ch;
    console.log("=======================================================================");
    console.log("Connected to client - ["+socket.id+"] for ["+channelName+"]");
    console.log("Transport Method - ["+io.transports[socket.id].name+"]");
    console.log("=======================================================================");

    try{
        var client = redis.createClient();
        client.on("connect",function(){
            client.subscribe(channelName)?console.log("channel subscribed to {"+channelName+"}"):console.log("Not Subscribed to {"+channelName+"}");
            client.on("message", function(channel,message){
            console.log("=======================================================================");
            console.log("Got message ["+message+"] in ["+channel+"]");
            socket.emit("notification"+channel, { msg: message });
            console.log("=======================================================================");
            });
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Redis server is not running !!");
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("Disconnected From client !!");
    });
});
```

On client side my code is something like this

```
<script src="localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

    // For one client ch=1 and for another ch=2
    var socket = io.connect("localhost:3000",{ query: "ch=1", "try multiple transports":false});
    socket.on('connect', function(data){
        $("div#status").html("<div class='connected'></div><span>connected</span>");
    });

    // For one client event is notificationchannel1 and for another client event is notificationchannel2
    socket.on('notificationchannel1',function(data){
        $("div#notification-div").append(data.msg);
    });
    socket.on('connecting', function(data){
        $("div#status").html("<div class='connecting'></div><span>connecting</span>");
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
        $("div#status").html("<div class='disconnected'></div><span>disconnected</span>");
    });
    socket.on('reconnecting', function(data){
        $("div#status").html("<div class='reconnecting'></div><span>reconnecting...</span>");
    });          
</script>
```

Please suggest me what are the things that I am missing.

Comment: @user568109 how does the question in your link relate to this question?

Comment: Sorry here is the correct link http://stackoverflow.com/a/16796375/568109

Comment: Yea but if I do so then how this reconnect will work? Cause If I write  iosocket.once('connect',function(){}) instead of iosocket.on('connect',function(){}) then I will only connect and reconnect will not work.